# Solr : How to search keywords starting with number and also contains characters other than numerals?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

How can I define field for predictive search in order to search keywords like "1902 story"?

If I enter character '1' it should return all phrases/words starting with number 1.

Current Field definition is as follows which does not support mentioned scenario:

```
<fieldType name="text_en_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <!-- can have a few filters of course -->
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="lang/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
            <!-- can have a few filters of course -->
            <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use some autocomplete functionality?

If so, you might want to take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester

You can use the RequestHandler described there to get your results.

You'll get a list of the words starting with the typed in value.

Comment: Hi, with this added this in solrconfig.xml <queryConverter name="queryConverter" class="org.apache.solr.spelling.SuggestQueryConverter"/> . I am able to search keywords starting with numbers but now I am facing issue with keywords like 1972's Story. Just want suggestion to consider the APOSTROPHE. Any Clue?

Comment: Along with mentioned above I also want phrases to be search not just individual words. So not able to find perfect combination in the field definition. Looking into PatternTokenizerFactory and PatternFilters but still no luck to crack this.